# How to add more than one frontname for same Module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

We need a module to function differently and show different UI if its comes with different frontname

*i.e*

If **Externalvendor/Module1** has routes like

```
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="routing1" frontName="routing1">
            <module name="Externalvendor_Module1"/>
        </route>
    </router>
```

For above routing I tried adding routing alias under **Custom/Module1** routes like

```
   <router id="standard">
        <route id="routing2" frontName="routing2">
            <module name="Externalvendor_Module1"/>
        </route>
    </router>
```

So here I was expecting when I access **domain.com/routing2** it will load same front pages like **domain.com/routing1** but currently it shows white page and I am not seeing any exception or no error log. How should be this done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below code for **Custom/Module1**:

```
<router id="standard">
    <route id="routing2" frontName="routing2">
        <module name="Custom_Module1"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

Comment: then this will became its own module and frontname. I need the second frontname for already available module and its functionalities like alias front URL

Comment: Then why not you are override the files because you cannot use frontname from another module. You need to override then

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for more than one frontname:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="detector_id_1" frontName="detection1">
        <module name="Package_Module" />
    </route>        
    <route frontName="detection2" id="detector_id_2">
        <module name="Package_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```